# Red Neuronal Artificial no lee valores float de un arreglo en Python

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy, keras

Quiero hacer una red neuronal que lea los valores `state` y `action` de un código para predecir una aproximación llamada `Q`. Para ello, leo estos valores en el código y los guardo en una lista para poder usarlos, estos mismos debo de convertirlos a float para que se usen correctamente, sin embargo, después del entrenamiento de la RNA no me arroja ningún valor, como si no me leyera los datos de los arreglos para entrenarlos. Adjunto código. Debo mencionar que utilicé Google Collab entonces los separé por cells.

Cell 1:

```
""" 
Q-Learning implemented like a dictionary.
The keys are (state, action) pairs and the values are 
the current estimates of Q(s,a).

"""

import numpy as np
import random
import copy

Q = {} #dictionary for the Q function [(state, action), value]

#estos arreglos funcionarán para guardar s y a para la RNA.
#entornos_estado = np.array([], dtype=float)
#acciones_agente = np.array([], dtype=float)
entornos_estado = []
acciones_agente = []

b = 0.95 #bias parameter (particular to the example)

Actions = [0, 1, 2] #list of possible agent's actions (particular to the example)

Q[(0,0)] = 0.0 ### some initializations particular to the example
amax0 = 0 ### some initializations particular to the example 

class Envsim: # the necessary methods and data structures for the simulation of the environment

      def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

      def rand0(self, state):
          s = copy.copy(state)
          s = s + 2.0*(random.randint(0, 1) - 0.5)
          #print(s, round(s))
          return round(s)
          
      def rand1(self, state):
          s = copy.copy(state)
          u = random.uniform(0,1)
          #print(s)
          if u < b:
             s = s + 1
          else:
             s = s - 1
          #print(u,s)
          return s
          
      def rand2(self, state):
          s = copy.copy(state)
          u = random.uniform(0,1)
          #print(s)
          if u < b:
             s = s - 1
          else:
             s = s + 1
          #print(u,s)
          return s   

      def Enviro(self, state, action): # Given a (state_t, action_t) pair, it generates (s_t+1, r_t+1)
          a = copy.copy(action)
          s = copy.copy(state)
          z = Envsim(self)
          r = 0.0
          ra = -1.0
          rb = 1.0
          rc = 0.0
          if a==0:
             s = z.rand0(state)
          if a==1:
             s = z.rand1(state)
          if a==2:
             s = z.rand2(state)
          else:
             s = s
             
          if -10 < s < 0:
             r = ra
          if 0 < s < 10:
             r = rb    
          if s == 0:
             r = rc  
          
          return s, r
                    
class Policy: #class for action selection and value updates according to the Q-Learning rule

      def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name

      def maxq(self, state, Actions):
          s = copy.copy(state)
          max = -10e10
          amax = None
          for a in Actions:
              u = Q.get(tuple([s,a])) #value associated to the key list [s,a]
              if u is None:
                 u = -20e10
              if u > max:
                 amax = copy.copy(a)
                 max = copy.copy(u)
          #print(s, amax)
          return amax
          
      def epsilon_greedy(self, state, Actions): #epsilon-greedy decisions for systems 
          #in which is possible to select any action at random given state s
          epsilon = 0.1
          z = Policy(self)
          comple = np.random.rand()
          if epsilon > comple:
             #chooses and action at random
             a = random.randint(0, (len(Actions)-1))
             #print(a)
             return a
          else:
              #Returns the action with the maximum Q-value
              a = z.maxq(state, Actions)
              #print(a)
              return a
          
      def updateq(self, s0,a0,r1,s1,a1):
          alpha = 0.2 #learning rate
          gamma = 1.0 #discount factor
          q0 = Q.get((s0,a0))
          if q0 is None:
                 q0 = 0.0
          q1 = Q.get((s1,a1))
          if q1 is None:
                 q1 = 0.0
          u = q0 + alpha*(r1 + gamma*q1 - q0)         
          Q[(s0,a0)] = u
          return 

### These are the generic fundamental classes for Q-learning ###################
class Agent:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def action_reset(self):
        action = 0
        return action
          
    def act(self, state):
        z = Policy(self)
        s = copy.copy(state)
        #a = z.maxq(s, Actions)
        a = z.epsilon_greedy(s, Actions)
        #print(a)
        return a
    
    def update(self, state0, action0, reward, state, action):
        s0 = copy.copy(state0)
        a0 = copy.copy(action0)
        r1 = copy.copy(reward)
        s1 = copy.copy(state)
        a1 = copy.copy(action)
        z = Policy(self)
        z.updateq(s0,a0,r1,s1,a1)
        return

class Environment:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def reset(self):
          state = 0
          return state
          
    def step(self, state, action):
        s = copy.copy(state)
        a = copy.copy(action)
        z = Envsim(self)
        s, r = z.Enviro(s,a)
        return s, r
    
    def done(self, state):
        if state == -10 or state == 10:
           vdone = True
        else:
            vdone = False
        return vdone

################################################################################
### Main Program ###

MAX_EPISODE = 500
#MAX_TIME = 3
MAX_TIME = 10
agent = Agent("James Bond")
env = Environment("in a dangerous environment")
print(agent.name)
print(env.name)
l = [None] * MAX_EPISODE #list to draw the learning curve
#action = agent.action_reset()
for episode in range(MAX_EPISODE):
    state = env.reset()
    action = agent.action_reset() #depending on the learning problem
    cur = 0.0 #cumulative reward for visualization purposes
    for t in range(MAX_TIME):
        state0 = copy.copy(state)
        action0 = copy.copy(action)
        state, reward = env.step(state0, action0)                
        agent.update(state0, action0, reward, state, action)
        action = agent.act(state)
        #print(action)
        #print(state, reward)
        cur = cur + reward
        entornos_estado.append(state)
        acciones_agente.append(action)
        if env.done(state) == True:
           break
    #print(cur)
    #print(Q.get((3,1)))
    l[episode] = cur
    #l[episode] = Q.get((-5,0))

#print(Q.items())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(l)
plt.show()
```

Cell 2:

```
#Parte 3.- Programar su código ya sea en Python o utilizando la librería SLM Lab.
#empezamos a desarrollar el modelo
import tensorflow as tf

capa = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]) #we'll use keras to save lines of code
modelo = tf.keras.Sequential([capa])
#an example on how it works with several layers

oculta1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, input_shape=[1])
oculta2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3)
salida = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
modelo = tf.keras.Sequential([oculta1, oculta2, salida])

#the training is faster in this case
modelo.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1),
    loss='mean_squared_error'
)
#we must convert the arrays to float to avoid errors
entornos_estado = np.array(entornos_estado, dtype=float)
acciones_agente = np.array(acciones_agente, dtype=float)
#training
print("Training in process...")
historial = modelo.fit(entornos_estado, acciones_agente, epochs = 1000, verbose=False)
print("Training completed")
```

Cell 3:

```
print("Prediction: ")
#probando con un valor de 100
resultado = modelo.predict([100.0])
print("Result: " + str(resultado) + " valor de aproximación de Q.")
```

Lo que me arroja esta última:

```
Prediction: 
Result: [[nan]] valor de aproximación de Q.
```

Comment: Sospecho del arreglo `acciones_agente`, pues tiene varios `None`

Comment: Efectivamente es así, de forma rápida solo reemplacé los `None` por `0` y me salió `Result: [[-7.5238595]] valor de aproximación de Q.`. Tienes que encontrar una forma adecuada de reemplazar esos `None` para no afectar tanto el rendimiento de la Red Neuronal.

Comment: Sospeché algo similar, pero como soy principiante en Keras entonces no estaba seguro, una disculpa. Muchísimas gracias por tu solución.